# random.randint with variables | How

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to generate a random number using parameters set by a variable but i get an invalid syntax error.

I have re written the code and made sure my variables are the same.

```
import random

Run = ("Yes")
while Run == ("Yes"):
  Number_1 = (input("What is the lowest possible number? > "))
  Number_2 = (input("What is the largest possible number? > ")
  Answer = random.randint(int(Number_1), int(Number_2))
  print(int(answer))
```

I expect it to get an answer of a number between the value of the variables Number_1 and Number_2 but i am getting a syntax error

Comment: Can you post the traceback ?

Comment: `answer` is not the same as `Answer`. Also you're missing a `)` on one of your `input` lines.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for the missing parenthesis but i am using the word 'Answer'as a variable name is that a problem? it is currently working but is there a difference?

Comment: According to the code you posted, you're assigning to `Answer` and then trying to print `answer`. That's two different names.

Comment: @khelwood i saw that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be

```
import random

Run = ("Yes")
while Run == ("Yes"):
  number_1 = (input("What is the lowest possible number? > "))
  number_2 = (input("What is the largest possible number? > "))
  answer = random.randint(int(number_1), int(number_2))
  print(int(answer))
```

A more pythonic solution would be to change the while loop to `while True:`

```
import random

while True:
  number_1 = (input("What is the lowest possible number? > "))
  number_2 = (input("What is the largest possible number? > "))
  answer = random.randint(int(number_1), int(number_2))
  print(int(answer))
```